# Data from database is not loaded to a variable on page load using angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-http

On page load, I get data from a database and place it in `$scope.x`. In my network tab, I get the list from my database but it is not loaded to the variable which I will soon be needing in a dropdown list by using `ng-repeat`. After the page load, however, when I click a button that retrieves data and place it in the `$scope.x`, I get the values already. If I do it like, I don't get the values on page load and just click the button that retrieves the data to the variable, I do not get anything as well. What am I doing wrong. Below is my code:

```
$scope.addProject = function () {
    debugger;
    console.log($scope.clientList);
    console.log($scope.userList);
};

$scope.getClients = function () {
    debugger;
    $http.get('/Clients/GetClients')
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.clientList = response.data;
        });
};

$scope.getAllUsers = function () {
    debugger;
    $http.get('/User/GetAllUsers')
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.userList = response.data;
        })
};

$scope.getClients();
$scope.getAllUsers();
$scope.addProject();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `addProject` function is being called before the data is returned from the server.

Modify the `getClients` and `getAllUsers` function to return promises:

```
$scope.addProject = function () {
    debugger;
    console.log($scope.clientList);
    console.log($scope.userList);
};

$scope.getClients = function () {
    debugger;
    ̲r̲e̲t̲u̲r̲n̲ $http.get('/Clients/GetClients')
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.clientList = response.data;
        });
};

$scope.getAllUsers = function () {
    debugger;
    ̲r̲e̲t̲u̲r̲n̲ $http.get('/User/GetAllUsers')
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.userList = response.data;
        })
};
```

Then use `$q.all` to wait for the promises:

```
var clientsPromise = $scope.getClients();
var allUsersPromise = $scope.getAllUsers();

$q.all([clientsPromise, allUsersPromise])
  .then(function() {
    $scope.addProject();
});
```

Comment: The `$q` service needs to be injected into the controller the same way that you injected the `$http` service.

Comment: Wow! That worked! Can you please explain why it didn't work on my original code also why do we need to add the $q.all or promise?

Comment: Read [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).

Answer (score 0):

you should get the data like this

```
var getclients= function(){

    debugger;
    console.log($scope.clientList);
    console.log($scope.userList);
};


getclients();
```

Comment: I am invoking the $scope.getClients() and $scope.getAllUsers() on page load already. Please check my code, It is at the bottom of the code.

Comment: @stackquestions, instead of   $scope.getClients()  you have to use getClients() see my answer my clear I am calling scope inside variable.

Comment: Now the addProjects is not being invoked when I apply your suggestion. Please see my updated code.